# Python: send email through Gmail and not citing the message's "Body"

Tags: python, email, smtp, gmail

I'm writing a little Python library that can send email through gmail. Everything works like a charm but the fact that the body of the message appears **cited** and I don't want that.

By cited I mean, that I have to click in this little thing to see the message:

[image]

The Python code in charge of "writing" the message's body and sending the email is shown here:

```
def set_message(self, toaddr, subject, message):
    self.toaddr = toaddr

    self.msg['From'] = self.conf.user
    self.msg['To'] = self.toaddr
    self.msg['Subject'] = subject
    self.msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))

def send(self):
    self.msg_as_string = self.msg.as_string()

    if self.server:
        self.server.sendmail(
            self.conf.user, self.toaddr, self.msg_as_string)
    else:
        raise EnvironmentError('Not connection to server')
```

If you really want to see the complete code, you can see it in [GitHub](https://github.com/imgglasses/em). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't attach the body of the message as an attachment, then.

Comment: That's the goal mate. But do I really need to hardcode the header of the message, like this: http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/code-snippets-source-code/using-python-to-send-email ? cause I ask the question in the possibility of a better method of doing things. @kindall

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852193/sending-email-from-gmail-using-python/3852316#3852316

Comment: Perhaps this can be of some use trying to understand whats happening
https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt